# Create sandbox environment for iOS MDM using simulators

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mdm

I want to generate test environment for generating the MDM environment in iOS simulators without using the devices.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.
Since MDM server requires UUID  for the device’s identity where it can send the commands.
But with the simulator we don't have any associated ID that can receive the commands